# Want to dis-associate an Apple ID (for iPad) with my iTunes acct on MBP

Tags: itunes, ipad, apple-id

I made mistake of using my iTunes account to sync and update my wife's iPad, and used her ID for this.

Result, all of her apps merged with my apps for my iPhone & iPad.  Got rid of those, but her iPad still shows up when I open iTunes in my User account on the Mac.

I have the problem on both Mav/iTunes 11.4 and Yoemite/iTunes 12.x.

Nov26,4:34 EST.

How do I stop that -get rid of her iPad appearance?

How do I respond to questions?  All I can see is the Comments option and Edit.  This window is what I get when selecting Edit.  Editing is not what I want to do.  I want to respond to the comment asking some questions.

Here is my response to the comment:

I cannot remember what I did specifically, but I did NOT use my ID, but used her Apple ID in my iTunes account. I have not wiped and restored her iPad. All I did was Delete her apps that suddenly appeared in my purchased list. I can sync and backup and everything else in HER user account on the same MBP, but in my User account, my iTunes , is where her iPad keeps appearing in the sidebar and trying to sync. I want it out of there.

shareeditclosedeleteflag
edited 2 mins ago

asked yesterday

modelamac
45925

Could you explain the mechanics behind how you "used your iTunes account to sync your wife's iPad using her ID"? It's not clear what specific parts of iOS or using iTunes on a computer have been set. Also, have you wiped the iPad and restored from her backup (or otherwise purged your account from that device so that it doesn't check in again under your Apple ID?) –  bmike♦ yesterday

I cannot remember what I did specifically, but I did NOT use my ID, but used her Apple ID in my iTunes account. I have not wiped and restored her iPad. All I did was Delete her apps that suddenly appeared in my purchased list. I can sync and backup and everything else in HER user account on the same MBP, but in my User account, my iTunes , is where her iPad keeps appearing in the sidebar and trying to sync. I want it out of there. –  modelamac yesterday

Could you take a stab at editing the comments into the body of the post. Comments get cleared and these details will be needed to try to assist you. –  bmike♦ yesterday

Comment: Could you explain the mechanics behind how you "used your iTunes account to sync your wife's iPad using her ID"? It's not clear what specific parts of iOS or using iTunes on a computer have been set. Also, have you wiped the iPad and restored from her backup (or otherwise purged your account from that device so that it doesn't check in again under your Apple ID?)

Comment: I cannot remember what I did specifically, but I did NOT use my ID, but used her Apple ID in my iTunes account.  I have not wiped and restored her iPad.  All I did was  Delete her apps that suddenly appeared in my purchased list.  I can sync and backup and everything else in HER user account on the same MBP, but in my User account, my iTunes , is where her iPad keeps appearing in the sidebar and trying to sync.  I want it out of there.

Comment: Could you take a stab at editing the comments into the body of the post. Comments get cleared and these details will be needed to try to assist you.